# Entities, JSF and abstraction

Tags: jsf, seam2

I'm  using Seam 2.2.2 and Seam-generate to generate a simple web project from a single table Database. This creates a simple JSF rendering the table's content.

Imagine I'll create N tables, and in this simple case, these tables will have the same structure as the previous. I'm not interested in using seam-generate again, I'm interested in using an abstract entity and create N subclass entities representing each table. Adding a small menu for selecting table 1, table 2, etc. Is it possible to render each table's content in the same JSF? My main objective here is understanding the usage of a view without duplicating code. Is there any literature regarding this specific matter?

EDIT : 
Seam-Gen creates an Entity for each table and two classes : "TableHome extends EntityHome" and "TableQuery extends EntityQuery". In this format, am I required to have one "TableHome" and "TableQuery" for each of my tables? 
Also, I've checked the Table per Subclass documentation and every example has a superclass mapped to a DB Table. So, is it that my Mapped Super Class must be a DB table?

Comment: Ok so you have one table and you expect more similar ones.. you want to map them in JPA / Hibernate using inheritance and then select content of each of them in a single page. Am i right?

Comment: Try... post something your tried and that e.g. does not work.

Comment: Maciej, that's exactly it.

Comment: @Kukeltje, I'll be trying in the next few days. When something comes up, I'll post it